# Azure Web App Bot - Linked to Another Account's Knowledgebase

Tags: azure, azure-qna-maker

Is there a way I can get the Web App Bot from one account query the knowledebase from QnA Maker of another account on Azure? With my corporate account, I can create a QnA Maker knowledgebase but I do not have permission to create a bot on Azure (requires creating a Microsoft App ID, which I cannot).

What I have done so far -

1. Build a knowledebase on QnA Maker
2. Used the QnA Maker client library (Python SDK) to query the knowledebase (works fine)
3. Hosted the Python app on Streamlit to give a GUI to the end users

I am open to other ways of building a "true" chatbot interfact like the web app bot or the one from DialogFlow.

Comment: Refer to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/QnAMaker/Quickstarts/get-answer-from-knowledge-base-using-url-tool?tabs=v1&pivots=url-test-tool-curl for querying the KB. Also, you can take a look at the [QnAMaker samples](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples#qna-maker-samples) in the Botbuilder samples repo and customize as per your requirements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, this is possible. You just need the the endpoint, knowledge base id, and EndpointKey which are given when you publish your KB as shown below.

```
POST /knowledgebases/********-****-****-****-************/generateAnswer
Host: https://QNA_SERVICE_NAME.azurewebsites.net/qnamaker
Authorization: EndpointKey ########-####-####-####-############
Content-Type: application/json
{"question":"<Your question>"}
```

With that information you can make the call from anywhere - bots, websites, whatever. Personally I like writing my own helper function to make the HTTP call with the above information. But you can also use a module like QnAMaker from the botbuilder-dialogs library (`const {QnAMaker} = require('botbuilder-ai')`). I would assume there is an equivalent package in nuget.

Comment: Thanks. Considering me a noob, what would you recommend my approach should be? Any suggestion for building a chatbot-like interface to access the QnA service/

Comment: I haven't built anything in DialogFlow but I know it is possible to call 3rd Party APIs. In theory you should be able to build the bot there and just send the queries to QnA Maker via API call.